# Angular 2 equivalent of Ember.Computed('Prop1','Prop2'...'prop n')

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

I am trying to port my Ember Application to Angular 2 ,
but i failed to see how can I  create
  `Computed Properties--Properties observing other properties for changes and the reacting`
in Angular 2.

```
[(myVar)] &&  onMyVarChange= new EventMitter();
```

Observes changes to it self and the react.

Any help/directions will be great.

Update :

Solved it using answer from @Nazim
Used typescript properties

TS (compoment.ts)

```
  private _isValid: boolean;
  public get isValid(): boolean {
    return this._isValid;
  }
  public set isValid(v: boolean) {
    this._isValid = v;
  }
  // A read only property
  private _show: boolean;
  public get show(): boolean {
    return this._isValid;
  }
```

Template (component.html)

```html
 <h2 *ngIf="show">Show Me</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, Angular 2 uses native ES2015 computed properties. For ex. you could define a Person Component:

```
export class PersonComponent {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
 }
}
```

And then use `ngModel` to bind the value of fullName to a template element.

Comment: so if i use `get isValid(){ boolProp1 && boolProp2 && boolProp3; }` Angular will automatically update the IsValid property bound to the template, when ever any on the property changes (boolProps) ??

Comment: Thanks for the hint, update my question with the solution in used.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :) Thx for the edit with the complete solution